# Toggle values of a matrix

Tags: algorithms

Ok the problem goes as follows. There's a matrix of N*M, with each element as "0" or "1". we select a specific x,y( x<=N y<=M) and starting from (0,0) to (x-1,y-1) ,we toggle the values.that is 0 becomes 1,and 1 becomes 0. I need to know an algorithm to calculate minimum number of moves such that all elements of the matrix are 1.

Comment: Please try to be be more clear. Try to add some details, otherwise is really difficult to answer!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the toggle affects the submatrix with lower left corner $(0,0)$ and the upper right corner $(x-1,y-1)$.

Look at the top row of the matrix: say, it's `0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0`. Read it from right to left: you'll have to  toggle the rightmost, which means toggling the entire matrix. The top row becomes `1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1`. You'll also have to toggle at the rightmost zero, making the row `0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1`. And so on: the number of necessary toggles is equal to the number of *transitions* (`01` or `10`) in the top row, plus one if the rightmost entry is `0`.

Now that you see what exactly needs to be done with the top row, you perform these toggles, then cut off the top row and   call the same procedure recursively.

To reduce the recursion level to $\min(M,N)$, you can do the above for the top row and rightmost column, and cut both off before the recursive call.